# hiding a child layer name link from mapbox and then making it visible when its parent layer is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, knockout.js, mapbox

I have an array of `mapLayers` coming in from a table in sql. These `mapLayers` have parent layers which contain one or more child layers. The element a that is being created is the one that holds the name of the layer 
I would like to make the layer name to the parent layer visible by default and then only make the child layer names visible when the parent layer is clicked.

The kind of functionality I'm seeking is similar to that of the bootstrap accordion. My index `emp[2] != null` is what determines if the layer has a parent or not (if its a child).Iif it is a child I would like to hide it then only display when the parent is clicked, but since there is no ID on the "a" tag I am not sure how to set the onClick event. Also if I assing ID to a each time its created it will mean a will always have the same ID and that will cause problems.

```
 $.when(getSecureData("/api/layers/"))
  .then(function (retmaplayers) {
            for (i = 0; i < retmaplayers.length; i++) {
                addLayer(map, L.mapbox.tileLayer(retmaplayers[i][1]), retmaplayers[i][0], i + 1);
                $.each(retmaplayers, function (index, emp) {
                    // pageViewModel.LocationViewModel.parentID(emp.fullname);
                    if (emp[2] != null)
                    {

                        pageViewModel.locationVM.parentID(1)
                }

 function addLayer(map, layer, name, zIndex) {
        var layers = document.getElementById('menu-ui');
        layer.setZIndex(zIndex)
        layer.addTo(map);
        // Create a simple layer switcher that
        // toggles layers on and off.
        var link = document.createElement('a');
        link.href = '#';
        if (zIndex == 1) {
            link.className = 'active';
           // link.class = 'accordion-toggle';
        if(pageViewModel.locationVM.parentID()==1)
       {
          link.style.visibility = "hidden";
        }
        }
        else {
            map.removeLayer(layer);
            this.className = '';
        }
        link.innerHTML = name;
        if (zIndex != 1) {
            link.onclick = function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                e.stopPropagation();
                if (map.hasLayer(layer)) {
                    map.removeLayer(layer);
                    this.className = '';
                } else {
                    layer.setOpacity(1.0);
                    map.addLayer(layer);
                    this.className = 'active';
                }
            };
        }
        layers.appendChild(link);
```

Comment: Did you hit submit too soon? Your question seems incomplete...

Answer (score 0):

> since there is no ID on the "a" tag I am not sure how to set the
>   onClick event

In general, you don't use elements' `id`s in Knockout (at least not in your viewmodel code), and in particular, you don't set `onClick` events. You use the [`click` binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/click-binding.html) on the clickable element.

You do not seem to be embracing the spirit of Knockout, which is that you manipulate the view elements by doing data operations on your viewmodel. You're creating DOM elements in your viewmodel code instead of in a binding handler.

Your `addLayer` should just be inserting a row into an observableArray. You should have (probably) a `foreach` binding for that observableArray, and within it a custom binding handler that turns each element into a map layer.